# How can I write a multi-line if block on Bitbucket Pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599478/can-if-statements-be-used-in-bitbucket-pipelines) I learned that Bitbucket Pipeline supports ifs statements.

How do I do multi-line blocks inside if statements?

This doesn't compute:

```
    script:
      - if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == "master" ];
        then;
          echo Line1
          echo line2
        fi;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that this works:

```
- if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]; then
- echo "We are on master"
- fi
```

Answer (score 53):

Bitbucket pipelines are written in YAML, so you can take full advantage of the YAML language.

For multiline, you can also use either `|` or `>` operators.

```
- >
  if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]; then
    echo "We are on master :)"
  else
    echo "We are not on master :("
  fi
```

More information:
https://yaml-multiline.info/

NB: I guess this use-case was just an example, but you can also filter pipelines steps by branches directly:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-SectionDescription

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, so much better as in the pipeline runs as single statement

Comment: for some reason using > operator was throwing syntax errors for the if else statement but using | worked perfectly